Does it make sense to "Let Cloudfront access S3 with VPC endpoint"
Currently I am making an infrastructure with Cloudfront infront of S3 for serving public static assets.
The customer requested that they don't like to have their public static assets being public on S3. They asked to put those assets inside VPN somehow with VPC endpoint
I don't really seems to understand the proposal form customer
Cloudfront is strictly public
S3 is outside of VPN
VPC Endpoint is to help services inside VPC access S3 without the connection surfacing to the internet
Only way I can think of is Cloudfront -> ALB -> VPC Endpoint -> S3 that could leverage VPC Endpoint somehow but that still seems weird to me and not provide any additional security or control

Your focus should be asking the customer for their desired result (eg S3 bucket not publicly accessible) rather than letting them dictate the architecture (eg using a VPN somehow).

Thanks @JohnRotenstein i think its just corporate paranoia and they dont even know what is the desired state. They just see that both s3 and cloudfront is not inside any vpc and asked to add VPC endpoint to make them "private" in sense of network segregration...

Just tell them that "Amazon S3 buckets are private by default".

It sounds like their requirements are:

They have some 'public static assets' in an Amazon S3 bucket
They want those assets to be publicly accessible via CloudFront (accessible to the entire world without authentication)
They would like to restrict access to the S3 bucket such that CloudFront can retrieve the assets but there is no public access to the bucket

If so, then the configuration would be:

Create the CloudFront distribution
Add a Bucket Policy to the S3 bucket that grants access to that CloudFront Distribution, but otherwise keeps the bucket private

See: Restrict access to an Amazon Simple Storage Service origin - Amazon CloudFront
